# listing code has missing some word

Tags: xetex, listings

```
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{identifiercolor}{rgb}{.4,.6,.56}
\definecolor{stringcolor}{rgb}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{inactivecolor}{rgb}{28,172,0}
\lstset{
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\def\fvm@Scale{.85}\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont},
    breaklines=true,
    frame=single,%
%   escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
    keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{blue}},
    stringstyle={\bfseries\color{stringcolor}},
    identifierstyle={\bfseries\color{black}},
    commentstyle=\color{identifiercolor},
    showstringspaces=false}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}
```

After define that

```
\begin{lstlisting[extendedchars=true,caption="trackingexample.m",language=Matlab]
function result_txt_vis()
clear all
t = importdata('result.txt'); Ani = 1;
switch Ani
    case 1
\end{lstlisting}
```

Something in `importdata('result.txt')` is missing!

[image]

and if i use C like that

```
\begin{lstlisting}[extendedchars=true,caption="Ex1.c",language=C]
#ifndef DEBUG
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("running-time: %e\n", time_spent); //display running-time
#endif
return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Something in `printf("running-time: %e\n", time_spent)` is also missing!
[image]

Comment: To define colors by values between 0 and 255, use the `RGB` model (instead of the `rgb` model).

Comment: yes, thank you,@PaulGaborit, i solve this problem by define `RGB` instead of `rgb`.

Answer (score 1):

Follows @PaulGaborit comment, use `RGB` instead of `rgb`,

```
\definecolor{identifiercolor}{RGB}{120,15,21}
\definecolor{stringcolor}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{inactivecolor}{RGB}{28,172,0}
```

then the problem will be solved.